# Remove row in datagridview with for each messes up index so it skips rows

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, foreach

I'm currently changing my project from a listview over to a datagridview, and ran into another "problem" when I try to remove rows that starts with x string.

```
For Each itm As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
If Not itm.Cells(0).Value.StartsWith(myValue) Then
    DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(itm)
End If
Next
```

So yeah, I have come to the conclusion that it messes up the index or foreach somehow, because after it removes a row, it skips the next row that took the others index/place, if that makes sense..

Comment: You are exactly correct.  When removing items from a list object always enumerate from last item to first item using step -1 which will always work.

Comment: Yep, I've learned that now, thanks :)

Comment: I learned that in college 42 years ago.